# Related rates problem with finding angle of carts moving away

Tags: calculus, derivatives

"Cart $A$ and Cart $B$ are connected by a rope of length $35$ m which
travels over a pulley. The pulley is located $12$ m above the ground. $Q$ is the point of the pulley along the ground which is closest to the ground.

Cart $A$ moves away fom the point $Q$ at $4$ m/s. How quickly is the angle formed by the rope about the pulley changing when Cart $A$ is $16$ m away from the point $Q$?

Is the angle increasing or decreasing at this point in time?"

So I drew a sketch of the diagram which looks something like this...

[image]

SO thus, I am told to find the rate of change of the angle when Cart $A$ is $16$m away.

So, I get $\tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{x}$

So, $\sec^2(\theta)\theta'= \frac{-y}{x}x'$

So I can calculate $\theta$ as $\tan(\theta) = \frac{16}{12}$ or $\theta = 53^{\circ}$

Therefore, we get that:

$\theta ' = \frac{-y}{x^2\sec^2(\theta)}x'$

Thus:

$\theta ' = \frac{-12}{(-16)^2\sec^2(53^{\circ})}(-4)$

$\theta ' = 0.0679$ $rads/s$

The angle should be increasing since the rope moves away from the pulley.

Is my work correct? I just need some clarification and to make sure I did it correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given $ x= 16, h=12, \dot x=4 ;$
Angle $\theta $ is made by Cart $a$ side of rope to vertical.
$$x= h\, \tan \theta,\quad \theta = \tan^{-1}\frac{x}{h}.\quad \dot \theta= \frac{h \dot x}{x^2+h^2} $$
Plug in, and that is done.
Neither Cart b  nor length $L$ need be considered. The pulley is like an automobile safety seat belt buckle serving to hold the rope tight.